# How to share classes, configuration files and web artifacts between projects using maven-war-plugin...?

Tags: spring, web-applications, maven, spring-security, maven-war-plugin

Can someone please help me with the configuration of the maven-war-plugin?

For security reasons I want to run two very similar Web-Apps on two servers for two different user groups, instead of deploying only one for all of them.
Therefore I would like to share as much code as possible between them.

I intended to create one war which can be also run standalone for development and reuse most of its items in two separate web projects. I would like to reuse e.g. the spring configuration files (applicationContext-XX.xml), jspx, css, ... and Java code. But I also need to write some Java classes which extend shared classes.

I wanted to try out the maven-war-plugin using a test project generated by spring roo. I already tried out several things but I have still problems with deployment.

If I only use the war then I can not extend any Java class as the code would not compile:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.pizzashop</groupId>
    <artifactId>PizzaShopCommons_WEB</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <overlays>
            <overlay>
                <groupId>com.test.pizzashop</groupId>
                <artifactId>PizzaShopCommons</artifactId>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Even if I do not extend any Java class my Tomcat (mvn tomcat:run) does not start as it does not find the jars which do lie in the lib folder correctly.
I also tried to use a second shared project which contains only the Java classes and the Spring configuration files and all the dependencies and is then packaged as jar. Runnning the main web app in Tomcat still results in an exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]
This file webmvc-config.xml lies where it should in the war (copied there by the maven war plugin).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.pizzashop</groupId>
    <artifactId>PizzaShopCommons_WEB</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test.pizzashop</groupId>
    <artifactId>PizzaShopCommons_SpringConf_Classes_Dependencies</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <overlays>
            <overlay>
                <groupId>com.test.pizzashop</groupId>
                <artifactId>PizzaShopCommons_WEB</artifactId>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
    <!-- <executions> <execution> <phase>generate-resources</phase> </execution> </executions> -->
</plugin>
```

The file structure in the generated war looks like this:

```
+---pizzashop-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
|   +---images
|   |       add.png ...       
|   +---META-INF
|   |   |   MANIFEST.MF   
|   |   \---maven
|   |       \---com.test.pizzashop
|   |           \---PizzaShop
|   |                   pom.properties
|   |                   pom.xml                 
|   +---styles
|   |       standard.css ...   
|   \---WEB-INF
|       |   web.xml
|       +---classes
|       |   |   builddef.lst ...  
|       |   +---com
|       |   |   \---test
|       |   |       \---pizzashop   
|       |   |           +---domain
|       |   |           |       Pizza.class ...
|       |   |           +---service
|       |   |           |       PizzaService.class ...      
|       |   |           \---web
|       |   |                   PizzaController.class ...                  
|       |   \---META-INF
|       |       |   aop-ajc.xml
|       |       |   persistence.xml  
|       |       \---spring
|       |               applicationContext-security.xml
|       |               applicationContext.xml
|       |               database.properties             
|       +---i18n
|       |       application.properties ...    
|       +---layouts
|       |       default.jspx ...  
|       +---lib
|       |       antlr-2.7.6.jar ...      
|       +---spring
|       |   |   root-context.xml
|       |   |   webmvc-config.xml 
|       |   \---appServlet
|       |           xx_servlet-context_xx.xml         
|       +---tags
|       |   |   create.tagx ...        
|       \---views
|           |   dataAccessFailure.jspx ...
```

How can I get this running? Is there any possibility to achieve this with only one shared project - one jar or war?

Comment: 2 things i see here: 1) make a multi module maven project and then use common things between your projects. 2) use maven overlay to inherit & extend your spring config files http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

Comment: Well, using multi module project is nice as it makes building all projects easier, as well as using inheritance for a central management of dependencies: [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)  Unfortunately this does not solve any of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

I integrated both Project Inheritance and Aggregation as both makes sense.

Hoping do get some feedback I will describe how I tried two solve the 2 problems (a) separating the commons code into a war and a jar project and b) not getting it to run due to the spring configuration files):

I tried out some more maven options but still did not find a satisfying solution:

I added a configuration element with **attachClasses** to the **maven-war-plugin** in the pom.xml of PizzaShopCommons_WEB to directly create a jar and a war overlay from the commons code:

```
 <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.1</version>
         <configuration>  
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
         </configuration>   
 </plugin>
```

The problem with the spring resources seems to be now that they are loaded twice (once from jar and once from war). This especially does not work for spring-security.

And that is essentially my next problem.

***What I already had tried and what does not work is:***
**1.** Adding packaging excludes in above configuration with the problematic spring configuration files. But this resulted in the war being built without the applicationContext files but the jars including them. Now the commons project could not be deployed as standalone any more so I did not try to run this:

```
 <packagingExcludes>**/applicationContext*</packagingExcludes>
```

**2.** Customizing the maven-jar-plugin to include only the class files which works if a jar is built but not if a war is built with an additional jar like shown above.

```
 <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
         <configuration>
           <includes>
            <include>com/**</include>
           </includes>
         </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

**3.** Excluding the generated jar from the final war and using the class files from the overlay. But I still

***The exceptions I get:*** 
For whatever reasons no matter what I change running

> mvn tomcat:run

always results in the same exception:

> DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:  Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]

So I tried to deploy it directly on Tomcat 7  which results in

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': 
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**')
>   is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to
>   be ignored. Please check the ordering in your 
>   namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration

Using eclipse WTP to deploy the code does not work at all as somehow the overlayed artifacts are kind of ignored. The error message in this case is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
>   I I copy the necessary code there manually, I am getting the same exception like when I deploy it on Tomcat 7 directly.

All the time the Commons project can be deployed and works correctly. 
Ideas from anyone with more experience with Maven and Spring are definitely appreciated!